# problem in converting date in fromat : dd.MM.yyyy to MM/dd/yyyy in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

Following is the example

Model

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}")]
    public DateTime Validity { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel
        {
            Validity = DateTime.Now
        });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View

```
@model MyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Validity)
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

When I select a date like 12.12.2011 it is working fine but When i use a date like 18.12.2011 it sets the value in the property(datetime) to 01/01/0001. This is a problem for me.

Comment: @ChrisF, if we don't instruct new users, chances are that we are having this very same conversation in one year time when the numbers will be different.

Answer (score 0):

You're expecting dates in "UK" format (day/month/year) but the conversion code is using "US" format (month/day/year).

The code that converts from a string to a `DateTime` needs to use the correct format string.

You need the [`DateTime.Parse` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ey1cdcx8.aspx) that takes culture and formatting information. You can give this method a list of possible formats so you can cope with a variety of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `<globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB" />` in web.config file.